# Cant find regex backslas in swift 3

Tags: regex, swift3

I am trying to parse the following string.  I am trying to just pull out the date and time that is inside the quotes in the capture group.

```
<time datetime=\"05/05/2017 18:30:00\">
```

In the RegExr tool on RegExr.com, I can use the following and it works fine.

```
<time datetime=\\"([\s\S]*)\\"
```

For the life of me I can not get this translated into Swift 3.  It just does not like the backslash.  I have tried to escape it with 2, 3, and 4 backslashes but nothing seems to work.  For example, I have tried using the regex strings:

```
"<time datetime=\\\"([\\s\\S]*)\\\""
"<time datetime=\\\\\"([\\s\\S]*)\\\\\""
```

Neither of these work.  I figured the first one would work to escape the backslash b ut it didn't.  Then I read another thread that said to escape the backslash, it takes 4 for some reason, but that didn't work either.

FWIW, I am not sure why the string I get back has a backslash in it.  I am getting from and HTML page and I don't recall it including those escape characters in the string before.  It would one nice if it just didn't have those.  I wonder if I can get rid of them before parsing...

Comment: How are you displaying this string value? Some tools (e.g. inspecting it in debugger) want to show you a quoted string and therefore will include backslashes (that aren't really there in the original string) when it shows it to you. Given that it looks like you're looking at XML, I'd be really surprised if those backslashes are really in the string, and it's likely an artifact of how you're examining the string.

Comment: So either remove the \\ references entirely, or replace them with \\? (e.g. zero or one backslash).

Comment: I am using the swift print command to show the string.  I tried the \\? and that didn't work either.  I agree that I dont think the characters are actually there, but not putting anything in for backslash does not work either.  I will have to dig deeper since when I just hardcode a string to be <time datetime=\"05/05/2017 18:30:00\"> for testing it finds it.

Comment: If the this is the form `<time datetime=\"05/05/2017 18:30:00\">` when it's inside a string variable, the literal, double quoted version inside code would this `"<time datetime=\\\"05/05/2017 18:30:00\\\">"`. Note that if html, the attribute `datetime=\"05/05/2017 18:30:00\"` literal probably won't be parsed this way.

Comment: If swift requires double quoted strings and you pass `"<time datetime=\"05/05/2017 18:30:00\">"` the regex engine sees `<time datetime="05/05/2017 18:30:00">` In that case, you need to give swift this string `"<time datetime=\"([\\s\\S]*)\""` in which case the regex engine sees `<time datetime="([\s\S]*)"`

Comment: Thanks.  You were spot on.  The problem lied in that I was actually in the wrong position of the string (i.e. I did not use the lazy (?) flag to make sure the previous tag I found didn't leave off in the wrong place).  So, I was actually parsing the completely wrong section of the string.  I have to reposition myself in the html string since some of the tags look the same - they are different based on their order.  I think I need to clean the up a bit :-).  Thanks a lot for your help.  You were correct, the backslash was not actually in the string and your final regex works.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice the greedy `[\S\s]*`.